# How to fix a Deprecation Warning, Firefox ProfilesIni has been deprecated in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, suppress-warnings, deprecation-warning

I want to use my custom Firefox profile and I'm getting a **Deprecation Warning** on

```
ProfilesIni myProfile = new ProfilesIni();
```

**@SuppressWarnings**. How do I fix this issue.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;

//System.setProperty("C:\\driver\\geckodriver.exe");

ProfilesIni myProfile = new ProfilesIni();

FirefoxProfile test = myProfile.getProfile("selenium 1");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(test);

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware there are two classes named ProfilesIni

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.ProfilesIni
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni
```

You can suppress the warning on class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class YourClass {
   ...
}
```

or on method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void foo() {
   ...
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public WebDriver startGeckoDriver() {
   WebDriver driver = ...;
   return driver;
}
```

or on `myProfile`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
ProfilesIni myProfile = new ProfilesIni();
```

In Eclipse you can add the annotation using the yellow warning icon:
[image: on class]

[image: on method]

Answer (score 2):

Just use the newer class as mentioned in the [javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver/3.141.0/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/internal/ProfilesIni.html):

> Deprecated.
> Use org.openqa.selenium.firefox.ProfilesIni instead.

Instead of
`org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni`
use
`org.openqa.selenium.firefox.ProfilesIni`.